# How to use resources from newer android SDK

Tags: android

i want to implement a simple animation to my dialog and i'm facing a little problem, I want to use the default animations from Android SDK 28

```
Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\data\res\anim\dialog_enter.xml
```

But when i'm typing @android/anim I only see a few of them: fade in/out, slide right/left.

If i just copy the dialog_enter.xml to my app anim folder, i need to follow the code in order to copy other files related to this animation, like the duration, the interpolator.

Is there a proper way to use those animation without copying them to my app folder **manualy**?

Comment: If you use resources of newer Android versions on the device with older Android version, it will likely crash. So you will have to limit your app min SDK to 28, or to copy the resource to your app resources manually

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Thanks you very much, but some of the resources are present in my minimum SDK folder, but not into @ android: